# How to use updatepanel with update progress in webforms?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to show a progress bar while printing some documents. But when I click the print button, the progress bar does not show.

here is my code in UI:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-6">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upCommands" ID="uProgress">
                                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                                     <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlLoader" Visible="true">
                                                        <div class="progress" style="height: 20px">
                                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="73" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">
                                                                <h4 style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: white; margin: auto">Printing...</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </asp:Panel>
                                                </ProgressTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upCommands">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlCommands" Visible="true">
                                                        <%--<a href="BIS_Edit.aspx?BuyerID=<%# Eval("BuyerID")%> &TransCode=<%# Eval("TransactionCode") %> &BuyerType=<%# Eval("BuyerType") %>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs waves-effect waves-light" id="cmdModifyBIS"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Modify BIS</a>--%>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-xs waves-effect waves-light" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("BuyerID") + "_" + Eval("TransactionCode") + "_" + Eval("BuyerType") %>' CommandName="ModifyBIS" ID="cmdModifyBIS"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Modify BIS</asp:LinkButton>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs waves-effect waves-light" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("BuyerID") + "_" + Eval("TransactionCode") + "_" + Eval("BuyerType") %>' CommandName="PrintBIS" ID="cmdPrintBIS"  ClientIDMode="Static"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print BIS</asp:LinkButton>                                                       
                                                    </asp:Panel>                                                   
                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void gvInformationSheets_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
             BuyerCode = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('_')[0];
             TransactionCode = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('_')[1];
             BuyerType = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('_')[2];
           
            if (e.CommandName == "PrintBIS")
            {
                if (isPrinting == false)
                {
                    isPrinting = true;
                    DisablePrinting(BuyerCode, false);                
                    PrintBIS(BuyerCode, TransactionCode, BuyerType);                   
                }
                else
                {
                    ShowToastr(this.Page, "Printing in progress, Please wait.", "Information", "info");
                }
               
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "ModifyBIS")
            {
                Response.Redirect("BIS_Edit.aspx?BuyerID=" + BuyerCode + "&TransCode=" + TransactionCode + "&BuyerType=" + BuyerType);
            }
        }

private void DisablePrinting(string BIS_ID, bool Visible)
        {
            string buyerIDinRow = "";
          
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvInformationSheets.Rows)
            {
                buyerIDinRow = row.Cells[0].Text;
                if (buyerIDinRow == BIS_ID)
                {
                    Panel pnlCommand = row.FindControl("pnlCommands") as Panel;
                   // Panel pnlLoader = row.FindControl("pnlLoader") as Panel;
                    pnlCommand.Visible = Visible;
                    //pnlLoader.Visible = !Visible;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I show the progress bar when I click the Print Button and Hide it when the processing of printing is done?